# Button Over Scroll view

Tags: qt, qml

I am developing an app and I have scroll view,inside I have a listView,i have created a button over the scroll view,i can see it but I cannot interact with it,i keep clicking on the list item everytime I want to click the button,how can I solve my problem to be able to click the button and without clicking the list view?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you show some code

Comment: Try change the order of declaration of the controls.

Comment: sorry about that ill add some code,Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your are declaring the button before the list. If your code looks like:

```
Button{
    // button
}
ScrollView{
    // scrollview implementation
}
```

The `ScrollView` will be "above" the `Button` stealing all touch/input events. If you want the `Button` to be above the `ScrollView` change your code to the following instead:

```
ScrollView{
}

Button{
}
```

Comment: @EngNokias if my answer solves your problem please tick it as accepted.